# Find index of annotation MapKit

Tags: swift, mapkit

I have been trying to performSegue for annotation, but this code generates different indexes and wrong places are shown in detailsView. Would be great to find out how it is possible to fix this.

Thanks

```
var detailsDict = [NSDictionary]()
var selectedPlace: NSDictionary!

func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, annotationView view: MKAnnotationView, calloutAccessoryControlTapped control: UIControl) {

  if (view.annotation?.isKind(of: PlaceAnnotation.self))! {
    let annotation = view.annotation
    let index = (self.mapView.annotations as NSArray).index(of: annotation!)
    let place = detailsDict[index]
    selectedPlace = place

    performSegue(withIdentifier: "showMuseumDetails", sender: self)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the main problem here is that you expect that `mapView.annotations` returns an array with all annotations being in the same order as your `detailsDict`-Array. I think that this assumption is error prone, because it would highly depend on the internal implementation of the MapKit framework.

A better way would be storing the Dictionary entry together with the `PlaceAnnotation` that you add to the map:

- Add a new property `details` to class `PlaceAnnotation`
- Set `details` value when you create the `PlaceAnnotation`
- in `calloutAccessoryControlTapped`, get back the details property from the PlaceAnnotation
- transfer this value to detail controller (maybe via your `selectedPlace` property, but I would prefer in instatiating the ViewController directly and setting the value).

Answer (score 3):

We can do it using this method

```
func mapView(mapView: MKMapView, didSelectAnnotationView view: MKAnnotationView) {
 let annotation = view.annotation
 let index = (self.mapView.annotations as NSArray).index(of: annotation!) 
 print ("Annotation Index = \(index)")

}
```